# How to fix datetime form between c# and SQL Server in different computers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I create applications for my customers and I usually get a `DateTime` conversion problem when application is deployed to other computers.

In Winforms, I have date selector control for users. A user selects a date and click button, then I do a SQL query to SQL Server. I filter the `SELECT` with the selected date. But I usually get `DateTime` conversion problem in other computer because of their regional setting.

Is there way to fix the `DateTime` format between C# and SQL Server, sometimes, SQL Server can be on a main server and users use my app in their client computer. Some SQL Servers accept `2014-08-20` and some accept `20-08-2014`. How can I fix this datetime for everyone?

Sample code here:

```
DateTime date_ = DateTime.Today;
.....
.....
sql = "select * from table where order_date="+date_.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Are you executing sql query from winform, or what is the usage ? I would use parametric sql query - like "select * from table where order_date=@order_date".

Comment: Use a parameterized sql query.  And not only because of this DateTime format issue - google will give you other more important reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if your `order_date` column is [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) type, you shouldn't pass it a string representation of your `DateTime` value. You need to pass it *directly* the value of `DateTime` with [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) of course. Because this kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

If your `order_date` column is character type, **change it to `DateTime`**. Character typed columns (`varchar`, `nvarchar` etc.) are for characters, `datetime` typed columns are for `DateTime`'s.

There is no point to save your `DateTime'`s as a `string`.

As a side note; in a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) in C# doesn't have any *implicit* format. It just a value that contains piece of times. String representation of it has formats.

Answer (score 3):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

So if you *must* use a string-based date format - use the **ISO-8601** format - but as Soner Gönül already mentioned - when using queries from C#, try to use `DateTime` as parameters - don't always convert everything to a string!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use date with month in text

```
DateTime date_ = DateTime.Today;
.....
.....
sql = "select * from table where order_date='"+date_.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")+"'";
```

or convert date to SQL datetime

```
sql = "select * from table where order_date=CONVERT(DATETIME, '"+date_.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"', 102)";
```

here is list of date time functions for SQL

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),100) +' '+ 'Date -100- MMM DD YYYY' -- Feb 5 2010
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101) +' '+ 'Date -101- MM/DDYYYY'
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),102) +' '+ 'Date -102- YYYY.MM.DD'
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),103) +' '+ 'Date -103- DD/MM/YYYY'
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),104) +' '+ 'Date -104- DD.MM.YYYY'
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),105) +' '+ 'Date -105- DD-MM-YYYY'
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),getdate(),106) +' '+ 'Date -106- DD MMM YYYY' --ex: 03 Jan 2007
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),107) +' '+ 'Date -107- MMM DD,YYYY' --ex: Jan 03, 2007
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),109) +' '+ 'Date -108- MMM DD YYYY' -- Feb 5 2010
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),110) +' '+ 'Date -110- MM-DD-YYYY' --02-05-2010
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),111) +' '+ 'Date -111- YYYY/MM/DD'
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),112) +' '+ 'Date -112- YYYYMMDD' -- 20100205
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),113) +' '+ 'Date -113- DD MMM YYYY' -- 05 Feb 2010


SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 20) -- 2010-02-05 10:25:14
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 23) -- 2010-02-05
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 24) -- 10:24:20
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 25) -- 2010-02-05 10:24:34.913
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 21) -- 2010-02-05 10:25:02.990


---==================================
-- To get the time
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),108) +' '+ 'Date -108- HH:MM:SS' -- 10:05:53

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),114) +' '+ 'Date -114- HH:MM:SS:MS' -- 10:09:46:223
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 22) -- 02/05/10 10:23:11 AM
```